# App already in production and uses CloudKit. I added new attributes in CloudKit. If I deploy from development to release, does it create a problem?

Tags: core-data, cloudkit, cloudkit-environments

My App already in production and uses CloudKit. I have added new attributes in CloudKit. If I deploy from development to release, does it create a problem? I mean for my app which already in release and don't know anything about new attribute.